# Problem with rebinding Ctrl to Capslock using Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am using AutoHotkey to rebind Ctrl to Capslock like this:

```
Capslock::Ctrl
```

I have also bound my home keys for movement while Capslock is held:

```
^h::Send {LEFT}
^j::Send {DOWN}
^k::Send {UP}
^l::Send {RIGHT}
```

Trouble is, I can hold Capslock and issue **one** movement combo, but subsequent taps of h,j,k or l while still holding Capslock results in one of those letters appearing in my editor. In other words, it's as if Capslock is being released, even though I am still holding it down. If I hold the actual Ctrl key and use the movement bindings, it works fine. Anyone know how to rectify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [solution](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=373462#) was kindly posted on the AutoHotKey forum by "VxE":

```
Capslock::
   Gui, 93:+Owner ; prevent display of taskbar button
   Gui, 93:Show, y-99999 NA, Enable nav-hotkeys: hjkl
   Send {LCtrl Down}
   KeyWait, Capslock ; wait until the Capslock button is released
   Gui, 93:Cancel
   Send, {LCtrl Up}
Return

#IfWinExist, Enable nav-hotkeys: hjkl

   *h::Send {Blind}{LCtrl Up}{Left}{LCtrl Down}
   *j::Send {Blind}{LCtrl Up}{Down}{LCtrl Down}
   *k::Send {Blind}{LCtrl Up}{Up}{LCtrl Down}
   *l::Send {Blind}{LCtrl Up}{Right}{LCtrl Down}

#IfWinExist, ; end context-sensitive block
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the PC reads capslock as a TOGGLE key.  Caps is pressed and it alters a state, then it's pressed again and the state goes back.  The other non-lock keys keep sending their signal as long as and each time they are pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but do you know how I solve the problem?

Comment: Probably to use a different key besides a LOCK key.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try scancode mapping method like [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Windows/A_2155-Keyboard-Remapping-CAPSLOCK-to-Ctrl-and-Beyond.html).