# How to remap Capslock+{?} to Ctrl+Alt+Shift+{?} in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to remap the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, but I want to also send any keys that I pressed after it.

For example, if I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> then I want AHK to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
likewise, if I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> then I want to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>.

The following doesn't work because it sends it before I press any trailing keys. (i'm doing this so I can map shortcuts to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[key]</kbd> and use the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to execute them.

```
Capslock::send {^~+}
```

Comment: Probably should be on SO.

Comment: Related question that may or may not help you: http://superuser.com/questions/168335/problem-with-rebinding-ctrl-to-capslock-using-autohotkey/168365#168365

Comment: @Hello71 - Do they send AHK stuff to SO?  I thought it seemed appropriate to be here.

Comment: @JNK: I guess it's more complicated AHK questions that get migrated to SO, doing a quick check.

Comment: Be aware that in AutoHotkey Alt is `!` not `~`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I looked in the AutoHotkey help file under "Remapping keys and buttons". The general pattern is `a::b` will make pressing key a send key b instead.
However, I couldn't get any of the following to work properly.

`CapsLock::^!+`
`CapsLock::^!Shift`
`CapsLock::^!LShift`

But that same help page describes how AutoHotkey internally translates the `a::b` remapping into two hotkey mappings. I used that example to make the following working script.

```
*CapsLock::
  SetKeyDelay -1
  Send {Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}{Alt DownTemp}{Shift DownTemp}
return

*CapsLock up::
  SetKeyDelay -1
  Send {Blind}{Ctrl Up}{Alt Up}{Shift Up}
return
```