# Caplock remapping to modifier keys fails on keyboard repeat

Tags: autohotkey

I've remapped my <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> based on [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/168380/how-to-remap-capslock-to-ctrlaltshift-in-autohotkey)

```
; Caps lock becomes ctrl+alt+shift
*CapsLock::
  SetKeyDelay -1
  Send {Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}{Alt DownTemp}{Shift DownTemp}
return

*CapsLock up::
  SetKeyDelay -1
  Send {Blind}{Ctrl Up}{Alt Up}{Shift Up}
return
```

And then in order to get Vim style navigation, I've attempted to remap <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to my arrow keys. I tried several approaches which did not work at all. I've settled on the following approach because it works for single key presses. But when I hold down, for instance, <kbd>Caps lock</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> in Eclipse, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> keyboard shortcut fires instead of simply going down a line. It only goes off for automatic keyboard repeats, never for the original key press.

```
^!+h::
  Send {Left}
  Send {Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}{Alt DownTemp}{Shift DownTemp}
return

^!+j::
  Send {Down}
  Send {Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}{Alt DownTemp}{Shift DownTemp}
return

^!+k::
  Send {Up}
  Send {Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}{Alt DownTemp}{Shift DownTemp}
return

^!+l::
  Send {Right}
  Send {Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}{Alt DownTemp}{Shift DownTemp}
return
```

Scrolling down 20 lines by hitting <kbd>J</kbd> 20 times is too tedious. Does anyone have a solution, or am I using something inappropriately? I have some other commands mapped to <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> and <kbd>Capslock</kbd><kbd>Win</kbd> (technically mapped to ^!+ and ^!+#), so fixes would preferably not break those. For instance:

```
; Caps lock + i becomes escape
^!+i::
  Send {Escape}
  Send {Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}{Alt DownTemp}{Shift DownTemp}
return
```

This works fine right now because I haven't had a need to hold down the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you must use Ctrl+Alt+Shift? I would think having CapsLock just toggle a variable would make this easier/simpler.

Comment: I was using Ctrl+Alt+Shift because it also had the benefit of letting me set hotkeys in other programs without worrying about collision. But that wasn't working anyway with my attempt, so nothing was lost by switching to your solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sort of alternative to what you are currently doing.  I have made it so <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> simply toggles the variable `cmd`.  Based upon this variable, your movement keys are enabled.  Any of these keys can be held in order to repeat multiple times.

I have also provided some methods, which may be overkill for right now but may prove to be useful to you later.

```
*CapsLock::    cmd := 1
*CapsLock up:: cmd := 0

#if cmd
    h::Key("left")
    j::Key("down")  
    k::Key("up")    
    l::Key("right")
    n::Key_repeat("^", "left")
    p::Key_repeat("^", "right")
#if

Key(key)
{
   SendInput {blind}{%key%}
}

Key_repeat(pfx, key)
{
    SendInput {blind}%pfx%{%key%}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solves my problem. #if and and the autohotkey method syntax are helpful to know about as well.