# Binding Shift to x using AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey, remapping, button-remapping

I'm trying to switch my <kbd>left shift</kbd>+ button with my <kbd>x</kbd>+ key on the keyboard. I tried Lshift::x but what happened was BOTH keys now had the functionality of just x. I looked at 
[Problem with rebinding Ctrl to Capslock using Autohotkey](https://superuser.com/questions/168335/problem-with-rebinding-ctrl-to-capslock-using-autohotkey/168365#168365) and it seems that this could fix my problem but I have no idea how to convert their answer to something that I can use. Would someone be able to do this? Thank you!

Edit, this didn't work:

```
 #ifWinActive
Shift::
   Gui, 93:+Owner ; prevent display of taskbar button
   Gui, 93:Show, y-99999 NA, Enable nav-hotkeys: x
   Send {LShift Down}
   KeyWait, Shift ; wait until the Shift button is released
   Gui, 93:Cancel
   Send, {LShift Up}
Return

 #IfWinActive , Enable nav-hotkeys: hjkl

   x::Send {Blind}{LShift Up}{Left}{LShift Down}

 #IfWinActive, ; end context-sensitive block
```

... of course putting the window after the ifwinactive's

Comment: You need two lines `Lshift::x` and `x::Lshift`. See [Remapping Keys and Buttons](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Two lines are required:

```
Lshift::x
x::Lshift
```